# Create ModelForm dynamically

Tags: python, django, forms

I have to equal modelForms and I want to make just one general instead of them.
Please see below code samples

```
class CreateStudent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields if not field.name == 'id']


class CreateGroup(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields if not field.name == 'id']
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
class CreateItem(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = custom_model_name #here I need to pass model from request somehow
        fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields if not field.name == 'id']
```

I want to have to links like `/create/Group` and `/create/User`
and I want to pass last part of url (`Group` or `User`) to form constructor and generate form basing on it.

Comment: why not just use `exclude = ['id']` for `ModelForm` instead?

Comment: can you please provide full string like it shoud look e.g. `model._meta.fields.exclude` or what ?

Comment: instead of `fields` just use `exclude = ['id']`. see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it this way. The meta stuff is evaluated at define time, so you can't change it depending on a request at runtime.

However since you've only got a limited number of models, and you're not customising the forms themselves, why not just define the forms and then use a dictionary to use the right one?

```
def create(request, model_class):
    forms = {
        'user': UserForm,
        'group': GroupForm
    }


    form_class = forms[model_class]
    ...
```

Comment: That is great idea. Your answers are cool as always, thank you very much :)